# CSS- float right not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a navigation bar for a website in HTML and CSS. I have an image of the twitter icon that I would like on the right side. I have tried using float:right on the image and its containing  tag. Can anyone tell me how I could do this? Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #C3C3C3;
  position: absolute;
}

img.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 21px 16px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7D848E
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

img.twitter {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

a.twitter {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="/static/arch.png">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com">
        <img class="twitter" src="/static/twitter.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Add `margin-left: auto;` to class `a.twitter` - I don't know enough about flex to provide this as an answer as I can't explain it properly, but it works

Comment: Try and use the `justify-content: space-between;` property on `.nav`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney that's probably the best answer - you should submit that.

Comment: @Sqnkov that will space out the logo and nav list, too, which I'm assuming OP doesn't want.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks but I can't explain it properly, if you can please feel free to add it as an answer with explanation - it would help me too so win win!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney roger that, posted an answer. I still think you could just answer with *"Add margin-left: auto; to class a.twitter"* and that would suffice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can align flex items with `auto` margins similarly to how you align block level elements with a defined width. In this case, you just want to give the twitter link `margin-left: auto` and the free space will occupy that auto margin. You can read more about auto margins with flex layouts in the spec here - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

> Prior to alignment via justify-content and align-self, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #C3C3C3;
  position: absolute;
}

img.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 21px 16px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7D848E
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

img.twitter {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

a.twitter {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="/static/arch.png">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com">
        <img class="twitter" src="/static/twitter.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the container is using `display: flex`, so the `float: right` is being ignored. The solution is easy: remove the `float: right` from the `<a>` tag and add `flex-grow: 10` to make it use all the unused space, and then move the img to the right with `float: right`. But that causes that the "clickable" zone of the logo is bigger than the image, which you can solve it adding the image and the link are within a div:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #C3C3C3;
  position: absolute;
}

img.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 21px 16px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7D848E
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

img.twitter {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  float: right;
}

div.twitter {
  display: block;
 flex-grow: 10;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="/static/arch.png">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="twitter">
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
          <img class="twitter" src="/static/twitter.png">
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: That will make all of the white space between the nav items and the twitter icon link to twitter.